# How to get information about exact value did generateUUIDv4() from Clickhouse engine has assigned to new row

Tags: sql, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I'm building logging process for my API. For each request I wish to save request/response json to database, assign unique ID to each request, and **return this id with response**. So, I need somehow know, what exact UUID was assigned to the newly inserted row

I'm currently using this query, and it works just fine, but I have no idea how to get generated UUID

```
INSERT INTO search_log (visitor_id, event_id)
VALUES ('test_visitor', generateUUIDv4())
```

While using Clickhouse python client I get just `[]` as response, which is quite uninformative

Comment: basically you should not need this, probably you should use `'test_visitor'` as a key. 'test_visitor' probably will be compressed better and will work faster than random UUID.

Answer (score 0):

ClickHouse does not have a mechanism to return the full or partial results on an insert.  You will have to query the table again. You could add a unique `insert_id` column to your insert and then query the table again to see the newly inserted values.

Comment: Do you know about any options to do that in python/FasAPI in a multiprocessing-safe way? (I know about uuid python standard library, but the catch is in multiprocessing)